# How do you train LUIS to recognize general nouns?

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding

I have a bot that was initially based on the [Zummer](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/Node/intelligence-Zummer) example. 
I would like the Search intent to pick up practically any topic you could search for as an entity.

I tried training using several example phrases but it became apparent that although the intent is correctly detected, the ArticleTopic entity only picks up the specific nouns provided as examples.

I also tried creating a regex entity using .* but this matches every complete utterance.

Is there a general approach to tell LUIS to capture some part of an utterance regardless of its contents?

Examples of what I would like to support:
Search for *, What is *, What are *, Tell me about *, etc.

Comment: Have you tried patterns, announced a week ago.

Comment: My initial try with Patterns was unsuccessful, but I will explore this angle some more.  One additional thought I had was to treat the verb phrase as the entity ("search for", "what is", etc), and strip the detected verb entity out to arrive at the query of interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use patterns and the entity which is specific to pattern which is Pattern.any. This entity return all the text which is where the entity has been marked.

It should give something like that :

- Search for **Entity**
- What is **Entity**
- What are **Entity**

Comment: I was not quite successful with this until I found the keyPhrase entity. However, when I was experimenting I didn't try the Pattern.any entity- I'll investigate this as well.

Answer (score 1):

This issue could be covered with the new [Patterns feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-how-to-model-intent-pattern) (using [pattern.any](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-tutorial-pattern#use-a-patternany-entity-to-find-free-form-entities-in-a-pattern)).

This feature helps in labeling the noun following a specific pattern.

If you add the pattern.any entities to your LUIS app, you can't label utterances with these entities. They are only valid in patterns. Here is another [example](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/4508) which explains how pattern.any feature resolves the issue of multi-word entity handling. I have reproduced your issue and it works. Hope this helps!!